# State/session management - Unity with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, unity-container, desktop-application

I am working on a desktop application with WPF and Unity. I want to understand, what is the best way to manage user `projects` in my application. I have a layered architecture with **domain**, **Data**, **Applications**, **UI** layers. I have a container which registers components from these projects. Some of them have a lifetime of the project.

Now, I haven't really used child containers before. I am wondering if with every project the user creates/opens, should I spin a new child container with registering the services I need for the entire lifetime of the project as a singleton. Currently, I have a singleton with a lifetime of the entire application and reinitialize the singletons across project boundaries.

- Looking for some design inspirations
- I believe the memory doesn't really get released when I close an existing project. Perhaps, disposing of a child container(if I have one) will solve this?

Comment: You've not explained anywhere near enough for a good answer. Please explain exactly what you mean by user projects?  How are you using the components? Do you even need containers for them? If this is all dynamic then how do you know the dependencies? If you don't then what does resolving components add?

Comment: User projects - Something similar to the class of desktop applications where the user needs to create a project and store data. For example, if I work on photoshop, I need to create a project and save it. So at a later time, I can open that project back up. For VS, a .csproj file stores all the information needed to bring the project back up. I have a similar need. The user stores a bunch of configurations which are stored as part of a project that the user is working on. Yes, I need containers as my services are injected by upper layers. eg: a UI controller calls method into a service.